# websocket handshake fails with django channels

Tags: websocket, django-channels, channel

**EDIT**: correction after @Ken4scholars comment below

I have the following consumer which fails right after connecting

**consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
#...

class ListGeneratedTokensByFileConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

   stop = False

   async def websocket_connect(self,event):
      await self.accept()
      self.stop = False

   async def websocket_receive(self,event):

    await self.send_json({"text":"received","accept": True})
    await self.send_tokens_list()

  async def websocket_disconnect(self,event):

    self.stop = True

  async def send_tokens_list(self):

    some_path = "..."
    while self.stop == False:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        the_message = {}
        if os.path.isfile("some_file.json")):
            with open(os.path.join(some_path ,"some_file.json"),'r') as new_tok:
                        the_message = json.load(new_tok)
        if not the_message:
            print("waiting...")
        else:
            await self.send_json(the_message)

    await self.close()
```

It always throws the error: `ERR_CONNECTION:RESEST` and the websocket disconnects with code `1006`. This might seem familiar to recent changes in django-channels but since I am sending a text once the websocket opens and send a message back from the consumer it should do the trick. Or is there something wrong?

**routing.py**

```
url(r'^myapp/sub_path/(?P<pk>\d+)/sub_sub_path/',ListGeneratedTokensByFileConsumer)
```

and the websocket endpoint in js is:

**.js**

```
var loc = window.location;
var wsStart = "ws://";
if (loc.protocol == "https:") {
    wsStart = "wss://";
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname + "sub_sub_path" + "/";
```

for info, with channels-redis==2.3.2, channels==2.3.0, asgiref==3.2.2, daphne==2.3.0, django==2.0.8

Comment: use `send_json` in this line `await self.send({"text":"received","accept": True})`

Comment: thanks @Ken4scholars. I tried and just edited the question. It still returns the same issue and only works with the fix of changing the routing endings so far.

Comment: Show the url you connect to from JS

Comment: edited the question to explain the construction of the url used for the websocket. The result is 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/sub_path/pk/sub_sub_path/'

Answer (score 1):

If you see something like in django logs:

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/your_route
WebSocket REJECT /ws/your_route
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/your_route
```

And you wrapped websocket router with AllowedHostsOriginValidator in the asgi.py like:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": django_asgi_app,
  "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
     URLRouter(
       chat_websocket_urlpatterns
     ))
})
```

Then you definetely should check the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable in the settings.py, maybe you forgot to put something in there. In my case it was just because I didn't specify my IP address, only localhost.

This is most likely not that the asker looked for, but I thought it may come handy to someone else, as there is not much info about the django channels in this site.